# dart pub build: exclude a file or directory

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am trying to exclude a list of files or directories when building a web application with dart's `pub build`.
Using this, as suggested by the [documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html#excluding-assets):

```
transformers:
- simple_transformer:
    $exclude: "**/CVS"
```

does not work:

> Error on line 10, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: "simple_transformer" is not a dependency.
>
> - simple_transformer:

Is there a way to do it (using SDK 1.10.0) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is currently no support to mark files as ignored by `pub build` as Günter already mentioned. The `.gitignore` feature was removed as it was undocumented and caused more trouble than it solved.

But you can execlude files from the build *output*. This means that the files are still processed (and still take time to process =/ ) but aren't present in the output directiory. This is useful for generating a deployable copy of your application in one go.

In our application we use a simple ConsumeTransformer to mark assets as consumed so that they are not written to the output folder:

```
library consume_transformer;

import 'package:barback/barback.dart';

class ConsumeTransformer extends Transformer implements LazyTransformer {
  final List<RegExp> patterns = <RegExp>[];

  ConsumeTransformer.asPlugin(BarbackSettings settings) {
    if (settings.configuration['patterns'] != null) {
      for (var pattern in settings.configuration['patterns']) {
        patterns.add(new RegExp(pattern));
      }
    }
  }

  bool isPrimary(AssetId inputId) =>
      patterns.any((p) => p.hasMatch(inputId.path));

  void declareOutputs(DeclaringTransform transform) {}

  void apply(Transform transform) => transform.consumePrimary();
}
```

The consumer requires a list of regex patterns as an argument an consumes the matched files. You need to add the transformer to you pubspec.yaml file as the last transformer:

```
transformers:
- ... # Your other transformers
- packagename/consume_transformer:
    patterns: ["\\.psd$"]
```

The example configuration ignores all files that have the `psd` extension, but you can add pattern as you need them.

**I created a pub package that contains the transformer, take a look [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/consume_transformer).**

Comment: Not simple to setup (see [Writing a Pub Transformer](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/)), but it works, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`simple_transformer` is the name of the transformer you want to inform to exclude the files. If you want to apply this to dart2js you need to use the name `$dart2js` instead of `simple_transformer`.
For more details about configuring `$dart2js` see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html

Comment: I tried $dart2js, but that does not exclude the files/directories with pub build. I think this is because dart2js only generates the Javascript, without copying any resource file. I think another transformer does that, but what is its name if not simple_transformer ?

Comment: I just tried using a `.gitignore`, but it seems to be ignored `pub build`.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether this was changed but according to the related issues `.gitignore` should work https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1093

Comment: There was a change mentioned https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/508 but I'm not sure if this means that it now uses or doesn't use `.gitignore` :-/

Comment: Thanks for the links. Maybe using .gitignore works for other versions of the SDK (I am using 1.10 because it is the last one supported by the Dart Editor).

Comment: After reading [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/9841#issuecomment-108362149) several times, I think the current behavior is to **not use `.gitignore`** (since about a year).

Comment: According to https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/508#issuecomment-109455280 , the use of `.gitignore` might depend on whether the built package is in a git repository or not. I tried creating a .git directory, just in case, but that didn't help.